# Need help advancing to the next record in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Ok so what I am attempting to do is I have a form to retrieve results. However, when I retrieve the results I can only retrieve the NEXT result if there are only 2 sets of results within the file. So I need help being able to retrieve the next sets of results if there are more than 2 sets of results in the file

```
For C = 0 To UBound(Scoring) Step 3
        txtSearch.Text = Scoring(C)
        txtName.Text = Scoring(C + 1)
        txtMarks.Text = Scoring(C + 2)
 Next
```

Comment: Your question seems not clear enough to me...

Comment: Honestly, I understand nothing... you see, this is programming and it is complex to understand if you only post 5 lines of code whithout saying what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: what i want ot achieve is having a form that reads data from an external text file which is read into an array. from this array the data will be seperated by ',' and the 3 sets of information within 1 record would be read into 3 different textboxes. however when i push a button that allows me to advance to the next record it will only work if there are 2 records within the external text file. So what i want to achieve is being able to have multiple records within the array and be able to advance to the next record without the program breaking because it is outside the boundaries of the array.

Comment: You want a button that advances thru each element on the array. But I see there a loop that will print all the data at once, overwriting every previous element all the time, until it finishes, so text boxes will show always the last record. Also I think that you should use Ubound(Scoring) - 1 because you start at index 0.

Comment: It's still not working, when i click the button to advance to the next record it's still skipping to the end of the record i attempted to use the Ubound(Scoring) - 1 but i don't know why it's still not working. Do i need to get rid of the loop that i had aswell?

Comment: As I can see now, you only need a variable to mark the position of the record. When you hit the button, adds 3 (C + 3), so you advance. To go backwards, subtract 3 (C - 3).  When C is greater than UBound(Scoring)  -4 then you are in the last record, so do not advance. And when C is equal to 0 then the same applies.

Comment: Ok but can you provide me with some sample coding to help me go through this procedure, I understand the process but I don't know how it would be implemented through the coding

Comment: Well, the fact is that I only know Visual Basic 6... Are you using VB 6 as well?

Comment: Unfourtunately no I'm using Visual Basic 2012 but I reckon I can apply the information from the coding to the new version of VB

Comment: Provide a piece of your code that I can try to modify with the solution. Also I see not clear why you said that every record had three values separated by commas, but I see in your code that every value is stored in an individual element of the array.

Comment: Ok the only code that I could think of for you to modify would be:     
    `code`Dim results() As String

        txtSearch.Text = Scoring(0)
        txtName.Text = Scoring(1)
        txtMarks.Text = Scoring(2)
                                                                                  For C = 0 To UBound(Scoring)
            txtSearch.Text = Scoring(C)
            txtName.Text = Scoring(C + 1)
            txtMarks.Text = Scoring(C + 2) `code`

But My file is sorted like this: 6268271,Adnan,6,1101,Mo,7,1224,Kris,13 
So all the different elements of data be saved and separated by a comma

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this could be:

```
Public intPosition as integer ' This variable has to be Public to keep the position

Dim bytStep as byte 
bytStep = 3

' Go forward
If intPosition <= UBound(Scoring) - (bytStep - 1)
    intPosition = intPosition + bytStep
    txtSearch.Text = Scoring(intPosition)
    txtName.Text = Scoring(intPosition + 1)
    txtMarks.Text = Scoring(intPosition + 2)
End if

'Go backwards
If intPosition >= 0
    intPosition = intPosition - bytStep
    txtSearch.Text = Scoring(intPosition)
    txtName.Text = Scoring(intPosition + 1)
    txtMarks.Text = Scoring(intPosition + 2)
End if
```

Comment: I Attempted this and unfourtunately its not working, It is only advancing to the 2nd position in the file.

Comment: Have you checked if the array has all the data from the file?

Comment: Yeah i did, i used a breakpoint in visual basic to check and all the data from the file was in the array.

Comment: What more have you in the code apart from what I wrote here? I hope that you aren't still using a loop...

Comment: no I wasn't I tried making this its own subprocedure and then calling the code back